# Looking for documentation to create simple blog script

Tags: oop, blogs

I want to build a simple blog which contains:

- A home page with blogs listed in the typical fashion: Title and content, plus read more to open a single entry.
- A publish area: Title and Content
- admin area to delete and modify posts.

No need for tags, users, or dates.

Take a look at this draft:

[image]

I have been looking for tutorials on the internet, but haven't found something simple enought to start working with.

> **EDIT**
>
> Found two nice tutorials. Haven't tested them, but looking at the
>   comments they seem reliable.
>
> - In this tutorial the steps look pretty straightforward and basic.
>     I'm    still a noob in OOP, so this might be right for me:
>     http://css-tricks.com/1907-php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/
> - This one is more elaborated, it contains users, dates, and tags. I 
>     put it here for future reference:
>     http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-an-object-oriented-blog-using-php/

Comment: Do you need to create it yourself? Or is it okay to use WordPress?

Comment: I need to create it myself, or rather say using pure php, without help from any CMS like wordpress.

Comment: WordPress is not really a CMS, but more a Blog. So you would be done if you could use it. :)

Comment: WordPress is a CMS. It is a system that manages content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found two nice tutorials. Haven't tested them, but looking at the
>   comments they seem reliable.
>
> - In this tutorial the steps look pretty straightforward and basic.
>     I'm    still a noob in OOP, so this might be right for me:
>     http://css-tricks.com/1907-php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/
> - This one is more elaborated, it contains users, dates, and tags. I 
>     put it here for future reference:
>     http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-an-object-oriented-blog-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

But since you can't use WordPress, what do you need?

You obviously got a pretty concrete idea of how to build it. I think you should refine that further, and start building.
Don't overdo it in the beginning. Start by designing a very simple blog. Each post containing just a title and contents. Skip the use of WYSIWYG editors, and advanced admin options. Just make a view page for a post, a view page for the list (chronological), and an admin page to edit or add posts. Publishing can be done by just adding a simple 'published' field, which you can toggle using a checkbox.

Don't bother with users yet. Just use basic authentication.

If you stick to those simple definitions, you should be able to get a working blog in a short time. After that, you will have some idea of the possibilities (of *your* possibilities too) and you'll be able to build on the base you got.

If there would be a very extensive tutorial on building a blog, you would eventually still just be copying the samples in that tutorial. It's more fun to think of something yourself and search or ask help for specific problems you run into.

Maybe you will have to start over at some point. Remember, if you build something for the second time, you'll build it faster, and it will be better.

But it won't be good until the third time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just do it. If you want to learn anything, simply figure it out. This is straightforward stuff. It'll teach you basic HTTP processing, some simple DB design and integration. Set up PHP/Perl/Python/Java/R/Common Lisp, add in MySQL or SQLite or whatever, follow a couple of HOWTOs, and just do it.

Really, you "don't need us" for this. Just break it down in to pieces. What are the right pieces? Whatever feels right to you. Seriously, unless you plan on hosting it to the wild world with some sensitive information, you really have nothing to lose here by just doing it yourself and pulling it off with amazing perfection or having it come out as a complete disaster. Both are rewarding in its own way.

If you have a specific question about a specific piece, you can come back, or head over to ServerFault, but you will likely be able to pull this off with even a teeny bit of persistence.

So just do it. Grab the keyboard by the plug and work the problem. It's better this way.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is just great run on tornado and app engine very basic and very good but i don't like comments and fb plugins etc try it [source code](http://github.com/bgolub/tornado-blog).

A previous ver without tornado is also available: [GitHub](https://github.com/bgolub/blog)